# MS Access VBA; select records from table filtered by date

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I have a table called tblAuditForms.  This table includes a date column called AuditDate.  The table stores the date in "short date" format, so the time is not stored in the table.  I want to select records from this table where the date matches 6/11/2020.  I've confirmed that there are many records within the table that contain this date.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim myAuditDate As Date
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset2
Dim strSQL As String

myAuditDate = CDate("6/11/2020")

set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblAuditForms WHERE AuditDate = " & Format(myAuditDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & ";"

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

rst.MoveFirst
```

The code makes it all the way down to the rst.MoveFirst line where it fails.  It appears the recordset is empty.  As I mentioned earlier, I know that the table contains records with that date that I'm providing.    I suspect the problem is with the format of my SQL statement but I can't figure out how.  I've also surrounded the date with # characters but that didn't appear to help.  Including ' characters around the date fails at the time creating the recordset as well.

I appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further examination of my table I discovered that the AuditDate field was in fact storing the time as well.  This was because those particular records had been inserted into the table using a separate VBA macro and were not subject to any validation rules.